# Use React component in InfoWindow content

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, infowindow

Currently I'm developing page with `google-maps api`.
I have a problem while implementing `InfoWindow`.
I wanna use `React Component` at content of `InfoWindow` like following..

```
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : <MyComponent />,
    position : { lat : ..., lng : ... }
})

infoWindow.open(map);
```

actually, I used `renderToString` like following

```
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : renderToString(<MyComponent />),
    position : { lat : ..., lng : ... }
})

infoWindow.open(map);
```

It's pretty good. But I can't use any function in `<MyComponent />` like lifecycle api..

So, Is there good way to use React Component in `InfoWindow`?

Answer (score 2):

I solved like following, but I'm not sure and little bit wired...

```
const myComponent = <MyComponent />;
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : renderToString(myComponent),
    position : { lat : ..., lng : ... }
})

infoWindow.open(map);

setTimeout(() => {
   ReactDOM.render(myComponent , $('.gm-style-iw > div > div').get(0));
}, 100);
```

Comment: This is because InfoWindow is only accepting string content. Since it's an embedded string object, React overflow is not working here. What you did makes complete sense but instead of setTimeout I would use domready event listener:

 `google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function(e) { AND RENDER REACT HERE })`

Answer (score 0):

React Google Maps is an excellent library with great docs (https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/)

Comment: Yeah I've used that library. But unfortunately, it has vulnerable point for rendering many markers... This(https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/495) is the issue about that.